# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence when using PIL to load an image

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, python-imaging-library

I get an error in the line data = np.array(data,dtype="float32"). It works fine if I do not use PIL.Image.open and instead use load_img() of tensforflow.keras. Can someone please help with what change do I need to make such that I can use Image.open() and get it to work?
The code is based on https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/05/04/covid-19-face-mask-detector-with-opencv-keras-tensorflow-and-deep-learning/

```
EPOCHS = 20
BS = 32

# grab the list of images in our dataset directory, then initialize
# the list of data (i.e., images) and class images
print("[INFO] loading images...")
imagePaths = list(paths.list_images(args["dataset"]))


data = []
labels = []
size = 224,224
# loop over the image paths
for imagePath in imagePaths:
    # extract the class label from the filename
    label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]

    image =Image.open(imagePath)
    image = image.convert('RGB')
    image.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    #image = load_img(imagePath, target_size=(224, 224))
    image = img_to_array(image)
    image = preprocess_input(image)

# update the data and labels lists, respectively
    data.append(image)
    labels.append(label)
    
# load the input image (224x224) and preprocess it


# convert the data and labels to NumPy arrays
data = np.array(data, dtype="float32")
labels = np.array(labels)
```

Comment: Examine `data` that  you give the `np.array` function.  Are the elements of the list consistent in size?  Is that the full error message?  Obviously there's something about `data` that makes it impossible to create a multidimensional array of floats.  You have to figure out what!

Comment: I understand that but I am not understanding why does it work when the data is created using load_img(imagePath, target_size=(224, 224)) but not with Image.open(imagePath)

Comment: TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars. This was also the part of the error.